# How to embed plain text into math mode?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, text

I really don't understand what's the problem with this piece of code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % declares a predefined package for math

\begin{document} %starts document

\begin{align} %starts a formula block
\text{Number of looks in\newline azimuth direction 
    &= \frac{\text{Pixel spacing slant range}}{\text{Pixel spacing azimuth}}\times \sin (\text{Incidence angle})}\\
    &= \frac{9.3685143}{3.5448059\times \sin (23.871\circ)}
\end{align} %ends formula block

\end{document} %ends document
```

When I try to build and run, I get a bunch of errors, including:

```
line 11: Misplaced alignment tab character &. \end{align}
line 11: Missing $ inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Misplaced alignment tab character &. \end{align}
line 11: Missing $ inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Misplaced alignment tab character &. \end{align}
line 11: Missing $ inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Misplaced alignment tab character &. \end{align}
line 11: Missing $ inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Misplaced alignment tab character &. \end{align}
line 11: Misplaced \omit. \end{align}
line 11: Misplaced \cr. \end{align}
line 11: Misplaced \noalign. \end{align}
line 11: Missing $ inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing $ inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing $ inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing $ inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing $ inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing { inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing { inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing { inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing \cr inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing { inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing { inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Missing $ inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Missing } inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Misplaced alignment tab character &. \end{align}
line 11: Misplaced \omit. \end{align}
line 11: Misplaced \cr. \end{align}
line 11: Misplaced \cr. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{align}
line 11: Missing number, treated as zero. \end{align}
line 11: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{align}
line 11: Missing number, treated as zero. \end{align}
line 11: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{align}
line 11: Improper \halign inside $$'s. \end{align}
line 11: Misplaced alignment tab character &. \end{align}
line 11: Missing $ inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Misplaced alignment tab character &. \end{align}
line 11: Missing $ inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Misplaced alignment tab character &. \end{align}
line 11: Missing $ inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Misplaced alignment tab character &. \end{align}
line 11: Missing $ inserted. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
line 11: Extra }, or forgotten $. \end{align}
```

As you know, line 11 is: `\end{align}`

Comment: `\text` can't span over a `&` column. You have to use a different approach. As well, use the `siunitx` package for a proper formatting of the angle within `\sin`

Comment: shouldn’t the `sin` in the second line be a product and not below the fraction bar?

Comment: @Tobi Congratulations, nobody noticed so far :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably you like to achieve this:

[image]

Instead of `\text` in first occasion you should use `\parbox` which enable to write two line text. After than you need to clean-up remedy with curly braces:

```
\begin{document} %starts document

\begin{align} %starts a formula block
\parbox{8.5em}{Number of looks in\\ azimuth direction}
    &= \frac{\text{Pixel spacing slant range}}
            {\text{Pixel spacing azimuth}}\times \sin (\text{Incidence angle})\\
    &= \frac{9.3685143}{3.5448059\times \sin (23.871^\circ)}
\end{align} %ends formula block

\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Considering Andrew Swann comment, use `siunitx` for units and make text width a bit wider with `geometry` package I obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % show page layout and make text width wider ...
                                 % in final use option "showframe" had to be removed
\usepackage{amsmath} % declares a predefined package for math
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document} %starts document

\begin{align} %starts a formula block
\parbox{8.3em}{\centering Number of looks in\\ azimuth direction}
    &= \frac{\text{Pixel spacing slant range}}
            {\text{Pixel spacing azimuth}\times \sin (\text{Incidence angle})}\\[1ex]
    &= \frac{9.3685143}{3.5448059\times \sin (\SI{23.871}{\degree})}
\end{align} %ends formula block

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
It seems that factor `\sin{...}` had to be in the denominator. I correct this my misunderstanding of given MWE. Above mine MWE and image of equation is now corrected.

Comment: You might consider adding `\centering` to the parbox.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, you have right, with centering of text in the `parbox` the equation looks better :-)

Comment: ok, thanks. but the second equation's right. I mean \sin should be in the denominator.  But the problem is solved. I guess I should add the documentation for all those packages to my notes. :-)

Comment: @sepideh, sorry I didn't figured out from you MWE .. I will correct this immediately.

Answer (score 7):

A slightly different approach (other than using `\parbox`), by applying the  more general `\genfrac` command and using it for `\textfrac`.

According to Tobi's comment above, the equations provided by the O.P. contained an error regarding the position of the `\sin`.

I also used `siunitx` for the display of the angular value.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath} % declares a predefined package for math

\newcommand{\textfrac}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}{\text{#1}}{\text{#2}}}
\begin{document} %starts document


\begin{align} %starts a formula block
  \textfrac{Number of looks}{in azimuth direction}
    &= \frac{\text{Pixel spacing slant range}}{\text{Pixel spacing azimuth}\times \sin \left(\text{Incidence angle}\right)}\\
    &= \frac{9.3685143}{3.5448059\times \sin (\SI{23.871}{\degree})}
\end{align} %ends formula block

\end{document} %ends document
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `\newline` in `\text`. The two-line descriptor on the left-hand side can be done with `tabular`, so you don't have to guess a width. Here I use centering, you can choose left alignment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  Number of looks in\\
  azimuth direction
\end{tabular}
    &= \frac{\text{Pixel spacing slant range}}
            {\text{Pixel spacing azimuth}\times\sin (\text{Incidence angle})} \\
    &= \frac{9.3685143}{3.5448059\times \sin (23.871^\circ)}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using [TexStudio](http://www.texstudio.org/) integrated with [MikTEX 2.9](http://miktex.org/) and you know while debugging, it doesn't give you much information. Maybe if I was using a better IDE, I was better in LaTEX codes. TexStudio is good and comfortable. The only problem I the debugging. Do you know of any other good IDE for LaTEX which can be used on a Win7x64 machine?

Comment: @sepideh Sorry, I use neither an IDE nor Windows. Debugging an `align` is a question of (1) using the right syntax to begin with; (2) commenting out all rows but one and check.

Comment: so how do you code in latex without any IDE?

Comment: @sepideh I use a text editor; for longer projects I use Aquamacs (Emacs for Mac OS X), for snippets `nano` from the terminal.